# Single threaded software performance on different architectures

Tags: multithreading, performance

In some paper, the authors are measuring how good the speedup of their sinlge threaded software is( where speedup is the reduction in processing latency of the input). They showed the results of the speedup on three different architectures. Following are te details:

- Pentium M at 1.5 GHz
- Intel Core 2 at 2.4 GHz
- Xeon E5520 at 2.27 GHz

and this is the resulting graph
[image]

Now, Xeon is a multicore and it showed a good performance interms of speedup. My question is that when your program is single threaded then single thread will be run on one core at a time. Yes, but when there is load on one core then your OS may switch that thread on to another core but still it just makes use of one core for the single thread of your software. So, coming to question why Xeon shows a good performance as compared to other two architectures?

Are there any other factors which makes Xeon perform better as compared to other architectures? Is this the clockspeed which is making its performance faster?

Comment: There are many parts to processor performance and it's a very complex field. I don't know what the paper is but I doubt the above comparison in meaningful in any way. Especially since it doesn't say what Core 2 and what Pentium is used.  Also it measures speedup. As compared to what? You don't say. To compare architectures you have to run this on the same computer with only the processor differing, the same clockspeed and the same cache sizes on the processor chips.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Speedup is the ratio of processing an input of I bytes using an old algorithm  and processing an input of I bytes using a new fast algorithm

Comment: So then Xeon does not "perform better as compared to other architectures". Your question is invalid. It might just as well be that Xeon was particularly bad at the old algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you are measuring performance difference between 2 algorithms, on different processors. Processors with a larger speed-up could either be especially good at the new algorithm, or especially bad at the old algorithm (or both). The following answer gives possible reasons for this difference. If I got the question wrong you can stop reading now.

Most likely the difference is not related to the number of cores. The tested algorithms were single threaded. When measuring performance of a program, the PC must not be under significant load from other unspecified programs - otherwise the entire measurement is invalid. Thus it is unlikely that the algorithm was interrupted often enough by the OS for it to have a significant effect on performance.

The difference is also not directly attributable to clock speed, because that would affect both of the algorithms equally. It may indirectly be related to clock speed, e.g. due to a different ratio of calculation speed to read/write access.

The difference will certainly be affected by various processor specific "features" (for lack of a better word), including, but not limited to:

- How many clock cycles are used for a division, multiplication, addition, and other instructions.
- How accurate branch prediction works for the given algorithm (see [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction)).
- How long it takes to fetch the different kinds of data used in your program (see [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)).

If the algorithms are compiled for specific architectures, the compiler may also perform various processor specific optimizations, replacing a set of instructions with another instruction specific the current processor. Or it may reorder a set of instructions when creating the program for one architecture, because of implicit guarantees that are valid for that processor.

The program may also depend on hardware other than the processor, for example if it accesses RAM, or the hard disk. The algorithms may also call the operating system, for example to print something on the console, to write to the hard disk, or to reserve/free memory. At that point the operating system, and the configuration thereof,  would become part of the difference.

And for great fun, you could measure the performance of the algorithms while a selection of different anti-virus software is running.

Answer (score 1):

Clock speed is not the only factor that determines CPU performance.  Other major factors are instructions-per-clock (IPC) rate and CPU cache size.  The Xeon E5520 is newer than the Core 2, so it's likely to have a more efficient implementation of the instructions being executed giving a higher IPC.  Additionally, Intel's Xeon chips typically have larger L2 and L3 caches than desktop chips such as the Core 2 or laptop chips such as the Pentium M, so the code or data the CPU is working with is more likely to be in the fast cache memory rather than the slow main memory.

Answer (score 1):

Process technology is a core selector here.  Pentium M has 90 nanometer feature sizes, Core2 is 65 nm, that Xeon is 45 nm.

Smaller is better:

- higher clock speeds.  That used to be barely valid back in the Pentium M days, over and done with today.  Processors are stuck at current clock speeds.  A slight tweak is dynamic clock rates, Xeon is 2.26 GHz nominal but can boost up to 2.53
- shorter distances for signals to travel, allowing them to switch at a higher rate.
- more transistors in the core, permitting extra execution engines and having more instructions in flight at the same time.  Hyper-threading takes advantage of the redundancy in the extra engines.
- bigger caches.  Pentium M has 2MB of L2 cache, Core2 has 4MB, Xeon has 8MB.
- more cores.  Pentium M has 1, Core2 has 2, Xeon has 4 (not relevant to this question).

Cache sizes are probably the biggest selector.  Xeon is expensive and usually married to a better memory bus, it isn't clear from the test whether the benchmark was bus-bound.  Probably not.